# Simplest way of doing a callback when two ajax request are complete

Tags: ajax, node.js

I have a Node.js application that functions as an API. I get a request, based on the action I perform some ajax request to another server, cache the results, and send the results back to the client.

Now for this new request I need to do two separate ajax calls, and give a response to the client when both of them are finished. To speed things up I do not want to nest them if that is possible.

Also, these ajax request are tricky, in the way that sometimes the server times our, or give bad results back, in that case I recursively do the same ajax request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, promises make this trivial:

```
 var http = Promise.promisifyAll(require("http"));
 Promise.all(["url1","url2"]).map(getWithRetry).spread(function(res1,res2){
      // both responses available
 }).catch(function(err){
      // error handling code
 });
```

An example of `getWithRetry` with promises can be something like:

```
function getWithRetry(url){
      return http.getAsync(url).catch(function(err){ 
           return http.getAsync(url); // in real code, check the error.
      });
}
```

However, you're not using them, so you have to manually synchronize it.

```
 var res1,res2,done = 0;;
 requestWithRetry("url1",function(err,result){
       if(err) handleBoth(err,null,null);
       res1 = result;
       done++;
       if(done === 2) handleBoth(null,res1,res2);
 });
  requestWithRetry("url2",function(err,result){
       if(err) handleBoth(err,null,null);
       res2 = result;
       done++;
       if(done === 2) handleBoth(null,res1,res2);
 });
 function handleBoth(err,res1,res2){
     // both responses available here, the error too if an error occurred.
 }
```

As for retrying, that can be a part of `requestWithRetry` itself, which should just check if `err` is not null in the callback, and if it is, retry once or twice (depending on your desired behavior).

Comment: Nice I will have a look at this. I am trying to do this with setintervals at the moment, but its turning into a big mess.

Comment: @SaifBechan `setIntervals` invites race conditions which are very fragile. In all honesty - Promises are really the way to go here. They compose and they're throw safe.